# Is there a way to find out more detail about my database connection issue?

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling

For some reason I can't connect to a Microsoft SQL database and the error I'm being presented with:

> Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:
>   mssql2012.netregistry.net in
>   /clientdata/apache-www/q/u/quest.org.au/www/phpinfo.php on line 47

... Really doesn't help me to work out why at all.

Is there a way to display more detailed error messages? I have the following already in my code:

```
// Errors, errors everywhere
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

But can my die statement in my connection string be expanded to provide me with more detail?

```
// Connect damn you.
$handle = mssql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Cannot connect to server")
```

Comment: Have you tried [`mssql_get_last_message`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mssql-get-last-message.php)?

Comment: Also, you have a syntax error after `$password`. Missing a `)`

Comment: Syntax error was from changing code into a SE format (fixing now). Unfortunately mssql_get_last_message still tells me 'Unable to connect to server' even though I can connect to it perfectly fine in my client

Comment: Reading the comments on [`mssql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/function.mssql-connect.php), it seems you may need to add the correct port for your SQL Server instance to your `$host` argument

Comment: @ElvisLikeBear Is PHP running on the same server as SQL Server? If not, from the server running PHP, try doing telnet sqlserverhostname 1433. If telnet works, you know that SQL Server is listening. Otherwise, ensure that SQL Server to listen through TCP (default port 1433). Try logging to the server from management studio and note down the full instance name (if it is not default).